# Get all step values from a while-loop

Tags: programming, procedural-programming, printing, iteration, numeric-array

I did a loop (first of my life) for an iterative calculation. Is it possible to get all step values as a matrix. That means the "xValue" variable should be like {215.108,219.688,...} and not only the last calculed value of the loop.

The code :

```
Clear["Global`*"]

"Variables"

\[Phi] = 20.0;
n = 3;
\[Phi]' = 0.0;
n' = 0;
\[Phi]e = 12.0;
b = 220.0;
h = 500.0;
cnom = 30.0;
fcd = -20.0;
Es = 205000.0;
Ec = 34000.0;
Nd = -200.0;
Md = 99.60;
As = n*(\[Phi]/2.0)^2*Pi;
As' = n'*(\[Phi]'/2.0)^2*Pi;
Ac = b*h - As - As';
d = h - cnom - \[Phi]e - \[Phi]/2;
Z1 = 0.9*d;

(*SigmaS1=(Nd*1000)/As+(Md*10^6)/(As*Z1)
\[CurlyEpsilon]S1=SigmaS1/Es*)

"Solver function"

Sol[Z_] := NSolve[{((Nd*1000)/As + (Md*10^6)/(As*Z))/Es*Es*As - 
      0.5*b*x*Ec*(x*((Nd*1000)/As + (Md*10^6)/(As*Z))/Es)/(d - x) == 
     Nd*1000, x > 0}, x, Reals]; 

"Loop"

{xp, Zn, StopCondition, counter} = {x /. Sol[Z1][[1]], d - (x /. Sol[Z1][[1]])/3, 100, 0};
While[
StopCondition > 0.1/100,
{StopCondition = Abs[Zn - (d - (x /. Sol[Zn][[1]])/3)]; 
 Zn = d - (x /. Sol[Zn][[1]])/3; 
 counter = counter + 1; 
{iter = Print[StringForm["Calcul N\[Degree]``", counter]]; 
 xValue = 3*(d - Zn), Print[3*(d - Zn)]}
}
]


xValue
```

Calcul N[Degree]1

215.108

Calcul N[Degree]

219.688

Calcul N[Degree]3

218.764

Calcul N[Degree]4

218.949

Calcul N[Degree]5

218.912

Calcul N[Degree]6

218.92

Calcul N[Degree]7

218.918

Out[3044]= 218.918 (Here should be all the previous numbers as a matrix)

Comment: Suggest using `NestWhile`

Comment: Or `NestWhileList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> variable should be like {215.108,219.688,...}

You could do

```
xValue = First@Last@Reap@While[
     StopCondition > 
      0.1/100, {StopCondition = Abs[Zn - (d - (x /. Sol[Zn][[1]])/3)];
      Zn = d - (x /. Sol[Zn][[1]])/3;
      counter = counter + 1;
      {iter = Print[StringForm["Calcul N\[Degree]``", counter]];
       Sow[3*(d - Zn), Print[3*(d - Zn)]]}
      }
     ]
```

gives

```
 {215.108, 219.688, 218.764, 218.949, 218.912, 218.92, 218.918}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed ! Big thanks !